# Not able to run ansible-playbook against ec2 host, SSH through terminal is working fine

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, ubuntu-18.04, ansible-playbook

I created an ec2 instance with port 22 open and I am able to connect to this instance using the private key from my terminal, however, I am not able to connect it when I try ansible-playbook. I have been using dynamic inventory.

The command I use for SSH and which is successful too (I am running the below command where the private key is placed):

```
ssh -i "test-key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-x-x-x-x.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

**Content for the playbook:**

```
---
- name: Hello World example
  hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: Printing Hello World
      debug:
          msg: "Hello World"
```

**The command I ran:**

```
ansible-playbook -i ec2.py --private-key /home/testuser/.ssh/test-key.pem -l instance_id playbook-hello.yml
```

**even I tried with:**

```
ansible-playbook -i ec2.py --private-key /home/testuser/.ssh/test-key.pem -l instance_id -e 'ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu' playbook-hello.yml
```

**Error:**

```
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Operation timed out\r\n", "unreachable": true}
```

**Other details:**

I am running ansible-playbooks on my MacBook Pro. The EC2 instance is running Ubuntu OS 18.04.

When I run ./ec2.py - I can see my instance is getting printed. AWS Keys are saved in home directory .aws/credentials folder.

**P.S:**
This question could be a duplicate of other questions available but I did not get any positive insight to match with my case.

Comment: [Network Debug and Troubleshooting Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/network_debug_troubleshooting.html#network-debug-and-troubleshooting-guide) might help you to move forward.

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) Is "`-l instance_id`" needed when there is only one host? 2) Post the code of the playbook. 3) Who is running the playbook (`whoami`)? Are you able to connect the host e.g. `ssh testuser@instance_id`?

Comment: Instance_id was given, somehow it was not shown here while putting the question, I am able to connect to the server using SSH and Private key (The normal way we use to connect ec2 instance). I think the 3rd thing which you mentioned is the cause here, I need to check that one and get back, but still, I am using the same user "ubuntu" to play the playbook so that should not be the issue. Because the same user is able to connect to ec2 instance with the private key.

Comment: Put the additional info into the question instead of commenting. One more question: Why do you use dynamic inventory when you're not able to connect? Make the test case as simple as possible and make the question [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Private key, user name, etc. - this is irrelevant here as clearly Ansible is having problems even connecting to the host in question ("Failed to connect to the host"). Are you sure you can `ssh whatever@x.x.x.x` from the very same node? (`x.x.x.x should be taken from the error message you redacted)

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki Yes, I am able to connect, I have added the information in the question too.

Comment: I have figured out the problem, I will post my answer soon.

Comment: OS-level security for applications? E.g. `ssh` client is permitted to connect, while Ansible is not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad to understand that the ec2.py script, which was used, only returning instances with private IPs. And because of that, it was not able to connect to the instance on port 22.

However, when I was doing ssh, I was using a Public IP or a DNS name.

So instead of using ec2.py, I executed the script using the public IP:

```
ansible-playbook -i a.b.c.d, playbook-hello-world.yml
```

a.b.c.d -- is a public IP of an instance.

If by any chance anyone gets a below error:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [a.b.c.d]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to a.b.c.d closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/python3: not found\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 127}
```

**Please use the below command:**

```
ansible-playbook -i a.b.c.d, -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3' playbook-hello-world.yml
```

Just make sure, pythos3 is installed on the mentioned path of the instance, where you are trying to execute the playbook.